# Make django date not editable

Tags: python, django, date

I am making a blog with django. I have an entry class, with title, content, publish date, etc.

The date field should save the date when the entry was created. But it changes if I edit the entry(If i changes the content or the title)

This is the code of the model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Admin:
        pass

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date',]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `auto_now` to `auto_now_add`.

From django docs:

> `DateField.auto_now`
>
> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.
>   Useful for "last-modified" timestamps. Note that the current date is
>   always used; it's not just a default value that you can override.
>
> `DateField.auto_now_add`
>
> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.
>   Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is
>   always used; it's not just a default value that you can override.